# How to differentiate between colliding objects in Box2D?

Tags: collision-detection, box2d

I need to differentiate between different points of contact in my racing game.

I currently have staticSensors which determine if the car is on the track or not, but I have created a second sensor to act as the 'finish line' but I am not sure how to differentiate the contact between the 'checkeredFlag' and all of the other sensors?

Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code:

## include "contactListener.h"

void ContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

```
bool isSensorA = contact->GetFixtureA()->IsSensor();
bool isSensorB = contact->GetFixtureB()->IsSensor();

Wheel * wheel = (Wheel*)bodyA->GetUserData();
CheckeredFlag * flag = (CheckeredFlag*)bodyB->GetUserData();

if (isSensorA)
{
    StaticSensor * sensor = static_cast<StaticSensor *>(bodyA->GetUserData());
    sensor->action();
    Wheel * wheel = static_cast<Wheel *>(bodyB->GetUserData());
    wheel->offRoad();
    return;
}

if (isSensorB)
{
    StaticSensor * sensor = static_cast<StaticSensor *>(bodyB->GetUserData());
    sensor->action();
    Wheel * wheel = static_cast<Wheel *>(bodyA->GetUserData());
    wheel->offRoad();
    return;
}

if (typeid(CheckeredFlag).name() == typeid(bodyA).name())
{
    if (typeid(Wheel).name() == typeid(bodyB).name())
        {
        flag->action();
        return;
        }
}
```